# skimage Pyramid Guassian not working as expected

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I'm trying to make an image pyramid that should just be smaller versions of the original image.  Instead, I'm getting what looks like static in the image.

Here's my code:

```
img = Image.open('orange.jpg').convert('L')
in_array = np.array(img)
for i,arr in enumerate(transform.pyramid_gaussian(in_array, max_layer=6, downscale=2, sigma=1)):
    Image.fromarray(arr,'L').save('orange-%s.jpg' % i)
```

Here's my input:

[image]

But here's the first image output:

[image]

Comment: The output will be a double array.

Answer (score 0):

> ..just be smaller versions of the original image..

If your goal is to make successive smaller versions of the image, the `thumbnail()` function can help you with that:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("orange.jpg").convert("L")
w, h = img.size
for step in range(4):
    w, h = w / 2, h / 2
    print "Now at %dx%d" % (w, h)
    img.thumbnail((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save("orange-%d.jpg" % step)
```